# JSON Object returned from a second page does not stringify in IE 8

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer-8

Consider the following scenario:

FooPage is page which, on clicking "Add", opens BarPage.

BarPage has a "Return" button. Upon clicking on it, it does the following:

```
function Add() {
    var selectedResources = [{ 
        "ResourceID": "10", 
        "ResourceName": "Foo", 
        "ResourceTypeName": "Bar"
    }];
    if (window.opener != null 
        && typeof window.opener.AddResources != "undefined") {
        window.opener.AddResources(selectedResources);
        window.close();
    }
}
```

FooPage, as you may see, has a function called `AddResources`. It does the following:

```
function AddResourcesCallback(selectedResources) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(selectedResources);
}
```

In Chrome, this works great - the string is created from the JSON in `JSON.stringify` and everyone is happy.

In IE8, however, this does not work. The JSON does not get created into a string - instead, `JSON.stringify` returns `undefined`.

I tried changing the scenario to this, as a test:

```
function AddResourcesCallback(selectedResources) {
    var selectedResources = [{ 
        "ResourceID": "10", 
        "ResourceName": "Foo", 
        "ResourceTypeName": "Bar"
    }];
    var result = JSON.stringify(selectedResources);
}
```

In this scenario, `JSON.stringify` in IE8 returns the correct value, just like Chrome. Meaning, that in IE8, when passing an array from page to page, you can't parse the array to JSON.

Is there a way to pass the Array without stringifying it first?

Comment: _"Any thoughts or ideas?"_ - Call `JSON.stringify()` in the `Add()` function and pass the resulting string to `AddResourcesCallback()`.

Comment: Did that, and that works obviously. But, is there a way to pass the Array without stringifying it first?

Comment: sounds like an issue with memory access across windows in IE8, what if you pass a function which returns this array?  does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a cross-window scope problem - the two objects have different `Object.prototype` prototype objects which might confuse IE (especially if one of them is garbage collected due to window closing). Try stringifying with the other window's `JSON` function like this:

```
// BarPage
if (window.opener != null && typeof window.opener.AddResources != "undefined") {
    window.opener.AddResources(selectedResources, JSON);
    window.close();
}

// FooPage
function AddResourcesCallback(selectedResources, json) {
    var result = json.stringify(selectedResources));
}
```

However, I think stringifying in one window, passing the string and parsing it back in the other window will be the safest approach.